# Thermocouple amplifier - single-ended vs differential?

Tags: amplifier, differential, thermocouple, single-ended

When connecting a thermocouple to an amplifier, what are the advantages of the differential versus the single-ended configuration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thermocouple circuits are just loops of wire, and in industrial situations may be rather long loops of wire.  In this case they are subject to what is called common-mode noise, in particular high-voltage induced AC.

The idea being any induced noise will appear essentially the same on both wires, and the differential amplifier will subtract it out.

Thus differential amplifiers provide a much cleaner signal than a single ended amplifier (with one side of the input tied to ground).  The ability of the differential amplifier to filter out common-mode noise is a parameter called the CMRR (common-mode rejection ratio).

Here is a thermocouple system using a number of Linear Technology parts.  The differential amplifier is the LT2057 (shaded).

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The least expensive and fastest-response thermocouples have a grounded junction. If your circuit also has a common ground you can tolerate a non-zero common-mode voltage on the thermocouple when a differential amplifier is used.

An alternative, applicable if there is only one thermocouple, Is to isolate the circuit form ground and allow it to float with respect to ground.

Alternately, isolated-junction thermocouples can be used, but they are both inferior in response time(meaning poorer control) and more expensive.

Here is a[n example of a circuit](http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/44-10/thermocouple.pdf) that can be used for either type- the 1M resistor provides a path for bias currents of the differential instrumentation amplifier if an ungrounded type is connected. (Actually a seasoned designer would likely use a lower value in high temperature electrically-heated applications).

[image]

Comment: "Actually a seasoned designer would likely use a lower value in high temperature electrically-heated applications" -- why so? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @miceuz Even a few uA at mains frequency will drive the inputs beyond the common-mode range of the amplifier. At elevated temperatures, insulators stop insulating so well, and bare heating elements are common, as are bare thermocouple elements.

Comment: I was experiencing exactly that at high temperatures - signal was clean untill I hit around 700 degrees, then I would start to pick up a lot of noise.

Comment: @miceuz Even great companies like AD don't always have app notes that can be trusted.